# Curl cant build with zlib using cmake for visual studio 11

Tags: visual-studio-2012, curl, cmake

Im trying to build curl with zlib for visual studio using CMake (GUI version)... i tried everything I found: setting ZLIB_PATH to zlib, setting WITH_DEVEL to zlib directory and so on but always get message

```
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I downloaded zlib distribution here http://www.zlib.net/ (version 1.2.8, zipfile format )
and cur distribution fro here http://curl.haxx.se/download.html (curl-7.35.0.zip)

somone can tell me how to do it or provide step by step instruction...?